# Creating layer representing non-intersecting area of two shapefiles in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geoprocessing

I have a shapefile for a country and a shapefile representing the mobile network coverage of an operator in that country.  I would like to create a shapefile that represents the parts of the country not covered by the mobile operator.  I tried Symmetrical Difference which worked around the edges but that did not get at the internal gaps in the network coverage map.

Comment: Several different geoprocessing overlay tools could  achieve this outcome, including Union (with suitable extraction by attribute) and a simple Erase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using the **Symmetrical Difference** SAGA tool from **Processing**: In the past I encountered some problems with the in-built algorithm, so you may do another attempt.

Before running the algorithm, make sure to activate the **Processing Toolbox** going to `Processing` > `Toolbox` and then type *Symmetrical difference* in the search bar for quickly finding the algorithm:

[image]

It will work as the **Symmetrical Difference** tool which is in the core of QGIS:

[image]

Comment: I was hoping for a solution in QGIS but this worked for me.  Thanks!  Curious to know why Symmetrical Difference worked in SAGA but not QGIS.

Comment: Sincerely, I don't know why: probably, some problems may arise in QGIS when the difference operation is done over more than two intersecting features. However, I'm glad it worked for you!

Comment: Short follow-up. Discovered I can run the SAGA Symmetrical Difference function successfully from within QGIS

Comment: You mean outside the Processing Toolbox?

Comment: No, I misunderstood your original suggestion and installed the SAGA GUI and used that initially.